# Tensorflow thread pools appear to spin forever, even after session is closed

Tags: c++, ios, tensorflow

## The quick version:

I'm using Tensorflow in an iOS project and seeing really high CPU usage even after I close the Tensorflow session like so:

```
auto status = session->Close();
delete session;
session = nil;
```

## Details:

Having read the code, I'm working under the assumption that under the covers Tensorflow is using the `DirectSession` subclass of `Session`, which explicitly cleans up its thread pools if it's configured to own its own threads. To ensure this, I updated the config when creating the session:

```
tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
options.config.clear_session_inter_op_thread_pool();
options.config.set_use_per_session_threads(true);
auto status = tensorflow::NewSession(options, &session);
```

But still in the profiler I see CPU usage in `Eigen::NonBlockingThreadPoolImpl<tensorflow::thread::EigenEnvironment>::WorkerLoop` continue to increase indefinitely after closing the session. It seems like the `Steal` loop never stops.

If I force it down to a single thread then there is no `Steal`ing. Like so:

```
options.config.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1);
```

Then Tensorflow stops hogging the CPU, but the threads still exist - they're just suspended, waiting (presumably) to be woken up to process new tasks. Obviously this isn't a real solution to the problem - I want to be able to use as many threads as is optimal.

Comment: using up the battery while idle sounds bad, this deserves an issue

Comment: I've submitted an issue with the Tensorflow folks: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12298